# Odd power of 2 plus even power of 2, is divisible by 6

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, perfect-powers

Prove $2^{2m+1}+2^{2n}$ is divisible by 6 for all integers $n\geq1$ and $m\geq0$. Equivalently one can prove $2+4^k$ is divisible by 3.

Comment: $4\mod 3 = 1\to4^k\mod 3 = 1\to 4^k+2\mod 3 = 0$.

Comment: Consider what $2^n\pmod3$ is for various $n$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $2\equiv -1 \bmod 3$ which trivially makes the sum $\equiv 0 \bmod 3$ (odd power plus even power).

Answer (score 0):

$$2^{2m+1}+2^{2n}=2\cdot4^m+4^n\equiv 2\cdot1^m+1^n\equiv2+1\equiv 0\pmod3$$

And the number is obviously even, so it is divisible by 6.

Comment: Can this be generalized? For example, any sum of the form $2^{n_1}+2^{n_2}+2^{n_3}$, with $n_1\in{1,4,7,10,13,...}$, $n_2\in{2,5,8,11,...}$, $n_3\in\{3,6,9,12,15,...\}$, is divisible by 7.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$2+4^k=3+ \left( 4^k-1 \right)=3+ (4-1) \left(4^{k-1}+...+4+1 \right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Quite obvious with congruences modulo $6$:

It is easy to check that 
$\enspace2^n\equiv\begin{cases}2&\text{if $n$ is odd,}\\
4&\text{if $n$ is even.}
\end{cases}$

Thus the sum of 
an even and an odd power of $2$ is congruent to $4+2\equiv 0\mod 6$.

Still more obvious for the equivalent assertion: $4\equiv 1\mod 3$, so
$$2+4^k\equiv 2+1^k=2+1\equiv 0\mod 3.$$